# Finding a prime factor using Cuda

Tags: cuda

I was not able to find other topics about finding the largest prime factor of a number using Cuda and I am having some issues.

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

__device__ int checkFactor (long long product, long long factor)
{
return product % factor == 0;
}

__global__ void factorKernel (long long product, long long limit, long long *result)
{
/******************/
/* Your code here */
/******************/

/* 1. Calculate f from thread ID    */
long long f = threadIdx.x;

/* 2. Caluclate number of thread    */
int numThreads = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

/* 3. While f is within limit       */
/* 4.   Check whether f is a factor */
/* 5.   If yes, write f to answer   */
/* 6.   Increment f appropriately   */

while(f < limit)
{
    if(checkFactor(product,f))
    {
        result = &f;
    }
    f += numThreads;
}

}

long long factor (long long product)
{
if (product % 2 == 0)
{
    return 2;
}
long long limit = (long long) sqrt ((double) product);

long long result = 1;
long long *dResult;

/******************/
/* Your code here */
/******************/
dim3 gridDim(256);      /* Create 256 blocks */
dim3 blockDim(256);     /* Create 256 threads per block */

/* 1. Allocate memory for dResult   */
cudaMalloc((void**) &dResult, sizeof(dResult));

/* 2. Memcpy result into dResult    */
cudaMemcpy(dResult, &result, sizeof(result), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

/* 3. Launch the kernel             */
factorKernel<<<gridDim, blockDim>>>(product, limit, dResult);

/* 4. Memcpy dResult back to result */
cudaMemcpy(&result, dResult, sizeof(dResult), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

/* 5. Free dResult                  */   
cudaFree(dResult);

return result;
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
long long product = atoll (argv [1]);   /* convert argument to long long */
long long f = factor (product);     /* call the factor function */

if (f == 1)
{
    printf ("%ld is a prime number.\n", product);
}
else
{
    printf ("%ld has a prime factor of %ld.\n", product, f);
}
return 0;
}
```

What this program was suppose to do is check if the threadIdx.x is within the calculated limit. If it was it would then use that threadIdx.x to checkFactor. If that treadIdx.x was a factor I wanted to set result equal to that threadIdx.x and then that would be a prime factor for the number.

Compiled  nvcc -o pfactor pfactor.cu

Executed: ./pfactor 11010010001

Expected Result: 23

Actual ~program hangup

I am not sure why the program doesnt stop running.

Comment: "I am not sure why the program doesnt stop running."   `blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;` does not give you the number of threads.  One of the blocks you launch will have a `blockIdx.x` value of zero (always).  Think about that.  You appear to be trying to use a grid-stride loop.  Set `f = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x*blockIdx.x` and set `numThreads = gridDim.x * blockDim.x;`.  And you need to make the fix suggested in the answer.  And I'm not saying that fixes all the issues in this code.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you setting result to a reference to f? The `&f` sets `result` to the address of `f` which is not what you want.

Switch:

```
    result = &f;
```

To:

```
   *result = f;
```

Other generic question, can you compile the CUDA examples?

Comment: I tried setting result = f and I was not able to compile.The error for that was along the lines of "type "long long" is not able to be set at "long long *""  As for the argv[1] this should capture the number when executed ./pfactor 11010010001.

Comment: error: a value of type "long long" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "long long *"

Comment: argv[0] is essentially saying "pfactor",                                                      while argv[1] is the number

Comment: You have to de-reference the result pointer. 

Replace with 
`*result = f;` 

`*result` returns the value of the pointer (IE where the pointer was pointing to)

`&f` returns the address (a pointer location) of `f`. This is why `result = &f` compiles but in no way does what you anticipate.

Comment: In response to arg[0] vs arg[1] you should just print to the console the number your expecting to be comparing. arg[0]/arg[1] is dependent on how you're running the program initially (I have no way of knowing).

Comment: `argv[0]` will always be the program name, never an actual parameter (unless you give custom parameters via an `exec` (Unix) or `spawn` (Windows) kind of call)

Comment: Updated, thanks I don't know what was I thinking when I wrote that (prolly just confused) . @Paul

Comment: @Joseph If you worked with languages such as Java, C# and others, it might be that (because in the args[] array received by the main method in those you *don't* see the program name)